# How to programmatically get list of users and groups that have access to a file or folder in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to find a way to get the list of AD users and AD Groups that have access to a folder or file that has broken inheritance.  I don't need to know how to find the inheritance broken, I have gotten that part but I am having issues finding each user or group that has access.  I do not want to see what users are within the AD group, I just want to see the name of the group that is accessing the folder.  The use case behind this is that we do not want secured folders shared to single users.  All of this must be controlled by AD groups only (site owners do not have access to add users to a secure folder).  Also need to find out if there are any files within the folder that do not inherit from the folder and are also shared to individual users instead of AD groups (hope this makes sense).   Here is what I have so far and it works to a point, but for some reason it is returning users that have access to the site elsewhere and also users who have limited access that I have to clean up later.

Here's the code I have written so far that sort of works.  It takes in the item object of the file or folder and a reference to a string. It scans the access and then builds a list of users separated by semicolon and returns true if one of the spuser objects is a user and not a group:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Provides list of users\groups that have access to a List Item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="spListItem">Item to check access of</param>
    /// <returns>semi colon delimited list of users\groups with access in a referenced list and boolean value indicating if a direct user exists</returns>
    public bool GetListItemUserAccess(SPListItem spListItem, ref string accountsWithAccess)
    {
        //string accountsWithAccess = string.Empty;
        bool IsFirstIteration = true;
        bool domainUserExits = false;
        SPRoleAssignmentCollection spItemRoles = spListItem.RoleAssignments;    
        SPRoleDefinitionCollection rolesInWeb = spListItem.Web.RoleDefinitions;

        foreach(SPRoleAssignment spRole in spItemRoles)
        {

            SPPrincipal spPrincipal = spRole.Member;

            //cast as SPGroup or SPUser to determine if is a SPGroup or User
            if((spPrincipal as SPGroup) != null)
            {
                SPGroup spGroup = spPrincipal as SPGroup;
                SPUserCollection usersInGroup = spGroup.Users;

                //report on each user in group
                foreach(SPUser spUser in usersInGroup)
                {
                    //check to see if it is a user group
                    if(!spUser.IsDomainGroup)
                    {
                        domainUserExits = true;
                    }

                    //add to list for report.
                    if(IsFirstIteration)
                    {
                        IsFirstIteration = false;                            
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        accountsWithAccess += ";";                            
                    }

                    //depending on the account type sometimes the Login name has the credentials and sometimes it has 
                    //a UID
                    if (spUser.LoginName.ToLower().Contains("<company name>"))
                    {
                        accountsWithAccess += this.ParseUserIDFromClaim(spUser.LoginName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        accountsWithAccess += this.ParseUserIDFromClaim(spUser.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if((spPrincipal as SPUser) != null)
            {
                //check to see if the user has limited access only (we don't report on this as this occurs when user has access to something in site)
                  if(!spListItem.DoesUserHavePermissions(spPrincipal as SPUser, SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                //check to see if it is a user group
                if (!(spPrincipal as SPUser).IsDomainGroup)
                {
                    domainUserExits = true;
                }

                //add to list for report.
                if(IsFirstIteration)
                {
                    IsFirstIteration = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    accountsWithAccess += ";";
                }

                //depending on the account type sometimes the Login name has the credentials and sometimes it has 
                //a UID
                if (spPrincipal.LoginName.ToLower().Contains("<company name>"))
                {
                    accountsWithAccess += this.ParseUserIDFromClaim(spPrincipal.LoginName);
                }
                else
                {
                    accountsWithAccess += this.ParseUserIDFromClaim(spPrincipal.Name);
                }
            }
        }
        return domainUserExits;
    }
```

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more, not sure what piece of the puzzle your missing. This code is a real mess as well, likely why there's no answers as it takes a long time to read and is overly nested. Would be worth having a developer refactor this.

Comment: Yah, I know the code is a mess at the moment.  I am still debugging the issue with it and I haven't had a chance to refactor it yet.  However, the issue I am having is that it is returning users that have access to the site, but not directly to the list item itself.  For example, I have instances where users with limited Access to the site are showing up in the RoleAssignments.  Everything I have seen so far indicates that while I am currently messy at it, I am on the right track for getting the data, so not sure why the extra accounts are coming through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that the code is returning both the users or groups that have access to the folder, but it is also returning back other users that have limited access to the item because they have access elsewhere within the site.

I finally corrected the issue by inserting the following code:

```
if (spRole.RoleDefinitionBindings.Count > 1 || !spRole.RoleDefinitionBindings.Xml.ToString().Contains("Limited Access"))

{
  //Process accounts
}
```

What this is doing is if the user has more than one roles bound to them for the list item or the one they have is not Limited Access, it will process the account.  Otherwise, it is one of these "phantom accesses" that don't actually have direct access granted to the list item